# Multi series bar chart to display point label

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I need to display the customized label in each bar. It is a multiseries bar chart using jqplot. I'm pasting my code here. This code is not working. Showing me a separate bar instead of multiseries. Please help me..

```
            function plotJQBarChart(critical, major, minor, warning) {
    var s1 = [32, 65, 57, 10];
    var s2 = [45, 56, 90, 30];
    var ticks = ['Critical', 'Major', 'Minor', 'Warning'];
    plot1 = $.jqplot('JQPlotBar', [s1,s2], {
        color: '#657383',
        shadow: true,
        grid:{background:'#F1F1F1',
        borderWidth:0.0,    
        drawGridLines: false},
        seriesColors: ['#9E7BFF','#3BB9FF'],
        barPadding: 2,
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true,labels:
                ['Severity', 'Wifi','Severity', 'Wifi',
                'Severity', 'Wifi','Severity', 'Wifi',
                'Severity', 'Wifi','Severity', 'Wifi',
                'Severity', 'Wifi','Severity', 'Wifi'] }
        },  
                      legend:{
                          show:true,
                         placement: 'outside', 
                        rendererOptions: {
                            numberRows: 1                      
                        }, 
                       location:'e',
                        marginTop: '15px',
                                labels:['Wifi','Severity']
                      },            
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            }
        },
        highlighter: { show: false }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding: `stackSeries: true` to your configuration?

Also, the way you are adding point labels is not right. See http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php

Answer (score -1):

Try to put `pointLabels` to each label in `series` property

```
series:[                
                {label:'Serie X', pointLabels: { show: true }},
                {label:'Serie Y', pointLabels: { show: true }},
                {label:'Serie Z', pointLabels: { show: true }}
        ],
```